# Dart 'const' usage with another 'const' values

Tags: dart, constructor

I need to create class with time range and i want use [Duration](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.7/dart-core/Duration-class.html) for this.
There is implementation:

```
final class Timing {
  final Duration lower;
  final Duration upper;

  const Timing.fromDuration(this.lower, this.upper)
      : assert(lower > Duration.zero),
        assert(upper > Duration.zero),
        assert(lower < upper);
}
```

In another class i create `static const` fields of `Timing` class. It is required, cos value of field will be used as default param of method.

```
class Communicator {
  static constTiming p1 = Timing.fromDuration(
      Duration(milliseconds: 0), Duration(milliseconds: 20));

  void sendMessage(String message, {Duration timeout = p1.lower});
}
```

Creation of `p1` generates `Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception. dart(const_eval_throws_exception)` error.

Is there way to group it ? I want to avoid ugly varaibles as `p1MaxValueInMillis` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use a const with static for this case as "Timing" can't be evaluated at compile time, but final will do the job. You won't be able to access the property of "Timing" as a const to use in a default parameter but you can do this:

```
class Communicator {
  static const Duration lower = Duration(milliseconds: 0);
  static const Duration upper = Duration(milliseconds: 20);
  static final Timing p1 = Timing.fromDuration(lower, upper);

  void sendMessage(String message, {Duration timeout = lower}) {}
}
```